# After fresh Raspbian-Stretch install my WiFi isn’t working on my Raspberry Pi 3 anymore

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

After downloading the newest image from the official Raspberry Pi website, I formatted the SD-card (8gb) and I put the new image on the SD with Etcher. After reinstalling the image I had **no WiFi** anymore, the RPI couldn't even find a wireless interface. Now, I can only connect to my RPI with an ethernet cable.

I have already tried numerous things. 
**I have tried:**

- updating/upgrading the OS.
- configuring the network settings via /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
- adding an external WiFi adapter from the company Edimax.
- editing the interface configurations via /etc/network/intefaces
- rebooting.
- reinstalling the OS again.

side note: Etcher gave me a weird Error after formatting my SD. Something about SSH and permissions.

**Some pictures of my current situation:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: **Post TEXT not images** The files you listed are NOT those in a fresh install

Comment: Well, I changed it a bit. Because it wasnt working after fresh install

Comment: side note: Etcher gave me a weird Error after formatting my SD. Something about SSH and permissions.

Comment: Etcher doesn't do SSH

Comment: interesting ... your linux kernel is `4.14.73-v7+ #1148 SMP Mon Oct 1` - but you claim the image you flashed is from June 2018 ... did you do an apt update/upgrade you didn't mention? and did you make other unspecified changes? since the latest kernel using apt upgrade is `4.14.70-v7+ #1144 SMP Tue Sep 18` - how did you update to a kernel that's only two days old?

Comment: Can you temporary change the WiFi country using raspi-config? Does iwconfig shows both wlan0 and wlan1 - after you plug your adapter in ?

Comment: @JanHus - if you look at the "pictures of" his "current situation" ... ifconfig shown NO wlan - so changing the WiFi country (only REQUIRED by the 3B**+**) isn't going to do anything

Comment: But if would verify raspi-config. Mine cannot find wpa_suplicant. I like to see how all these "configuration / setup " files look BEFORE they are modified. Is there such resource?

Comment: to see what they look like, don't touch them after flashing :p

Comment: I have almost tried everything. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After flashing the SD Card do nothing else then booting without any configuration. To reduce side effects I suggest to use first [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-06-27](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) just for testing. With `ip link show` you must see at least one wifi interface, the one from the build in wifi chip, mostly named **wlan0**. You can also look if the wifi interface is blocked with (for example output from my RPi3B+):

```
rpi ~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

If the wifi interface is soft blocked you can enable it with `rfkill unblock 0` (look at *man rfkill*). Hard blocked interfaces cannot be unblocked this way.

If you do not see any wifi interface, it's very likely that you have a hardware problem.

Comment: rfkill list shows nothing. I guess I have hardware problems. Fuck, now I can throw my first RPI away.

Comment: Already bought a new one. New one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To **aid in resolving the issue** use this resource

https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant

In "examples"

wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -d