# RPi3 Model B - no wireless interface found

Tags: pi-3, wifi

i'm new at RPi. Today, i installed NOOBS and tried to turn on Wi-Fi. When i clicked network icon (next to the bluetooth icon), it written "no wireless interfaces found".

I typed to terminal "sudo ifconfig". There is no wlan0. I edited wpa_supplicant.conf, it didn't change anything. I tried to change wifi country code on raspi-config but  "no wireless interface found","There was an error running option I4 Change Wi-Fi Country" errors showed up. So what should i do?

Comment: I asked the one that used this device before. He is not sure, he encountered with some errors about it

Comment: try a different image - raspbian (full or lite) - I know NOOBS is supposed to be "easy", but it seems it's easily broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a console with `ip link show` you should always see an interface for wifi, mostly **wlan0**, no matter if wifi works or not. if not, it is likely that you have a hardware problem. Look at [After fresh Raspbian-Stretch install my WiFi isn’t working on my Raspberry Pi 3 anymore](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89627/79866) for further information. To narrow down the problem you my consider only for testing to install [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-06-27](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). It does not need much resources and may reduce side effects in configuring wifi.

Comment: it seem broken, just showed up eth. Thanks for your answers.